# DrawableStart is messing with me

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to add an image to the left of the text in the button. So I used the below piece of code

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_login"
    />
```

After doing this, the Layout Editor shows me this [image]

But since there's no `android:drawableStart` Android Studio complains to me about this and when I add it. The final code looks like this:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_login"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_login"/>
```

and now the button looks like this -_- [image]

I know, one solution could be to just ignore the warning but I don't think that's what's recommended.
P.S. If I just do drawableStart then also no image is shown.
What should I do, am I missing something crucial?

Answer (score 0):

You can just get rid of the warning in this case by doing (Windows) alt+enter and then ignore it for that specific view

That will add a attribute so you'll still know it's ignored on purpose when looking at the view.

Comment: Yeah but that's the same as ignoring the warning. But I want to know why that's happening. Thanks for answering

Comment: Sorry, can't help you further. Might be a problem with the SDK though so don't worry about it too much

Answer (score 0):

I think it just need to set layout direction :
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
it will be automaticlly replace